# A formula satisfiable from an infinite sequence of formulas

Tags: propositional-calculus

> Let $\lbrace\varphi_n\rbrace_{n\geq 1}$ be a sequence of semantically inequivalent formulas s.t. $\vDash \varphi_{n+1} \to \varphi_{n}$. Is there a formula $\psi$ s.t. $(\lbrace\varphi_n\rbrace_{n\geq 1}\vDash \psi) \land (\forall n\geq 1.\psi\vDash \varphi_{n})$?

I think there is no such $\psi$ but I can't formulate the proof quite yet.
By assuming such $\psi$ exists and using compactness theorem we can have a finite subset $\Delta \subset \lbrace\varphi_n\rbrace_{n\geq 1}$ s.t. $\forall n\geq 1.\Delta \vDash \varphi_{n}$ but I can't see where does a contradiction suppose to come from.

Comment: What do you mean by $\lbrace\varphi_n\rbrace_{n\geq 1}\vDash \psi \land \forall n\geq 1.\psi\vDash \varphi_{n}$? It doesn't appear to be well formed to me, because there are two $\vDash$ symbols in the same line. Do you mean $(\lbrace\varphi_n\rbrace_{n\geq 1}\vDash \psi )\land( \forall n\geq 1.\psi\vDash \varphi_{n})$?

Comment: @user400188 yes. I'll edit. Explicitly put $\psi$ is semantically entailed from the infinite set of $\varphi_{n}$ and semantically entails any $\varphi_{n}$

Comment: One last question, (more for my own sake than for readability of the question), by "syntactical equivalence" of two formulas, do you mean provable equivalence $\dashv\vdash$, or that the formulas are the same strings?

Comment: @user400188 The same strings

Comment: @gbi1977 Are you sure, that by "syntactically inequivalent" you just meanthat they are different strings? Because, if so, there is an easy example of the described result holding: just take a propositional variable $p$, $\varphi_{n}=\bigwedge_{i=1}^{n}p$ and $\psi=p$.

Comment: @GVT Yes, in hindsight it does seem like it should have meant semantically inequivalent. I'll edit the question.

Comment: @gbi1977 Thank you! Now you have answers to both cases: if "inequivalent" refers  merely to different strings, I gave an example in comments to the result and a counterexample in my answer; if it refers to semantically, and syntactically, inequivalence, my counterexample still works, but you also have Noah Schweber's sharper answer, proving there are no cases in which the result holds.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe this counts as a counterexample, although things will probably become clearer if the original poster clarifies some minor points I asked about in the comments.

So, take the set of all propositional variables to be $\{p_{n} : n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}\}$ and define
$$\varphi_{n}=\bigwedge_{i=1}^{n}p_{i};$$
they are certainly inequivalent, and also satisfy $\vDash\varphi_{n+1}\rightarrow\varphi_{n}$ (actually $\varphi_{m}\vDash\varphi_{n}$ for every $m\geq n$). But there can not be any formula $\psi$ satisfying the desired properties: if $\psi\vDash\varphi_{n}$, for every $n\geq 1$, let $p_{i_{1}}, ... , p_{i_{n}}$ be the variables in $\psi$; if $\psi$ is not a contradiction, take a valuation $\nu$ such that $\nu(\psi)=1$ and define $\nu'$ such that $\nu'(p_{i})=\nu(p_{i})$, for $i\leq M=\max\{i_{1}, ... , i_{n}\}$, and $\nu'(p_{i})=0$ for $i>M$. Then $\nu'(\psi)=1$ but $\nu(\varphi_{i})=0$, for $i>M$, so we must have that $\psi$ is a contradiction.

But then you cannot have $\{\varphi_{n} : n\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}\}\vDash\psi$: take the valuation $\nu$ such that $\nu(p_{i})=1$, for every $i\in\mathbb{N}\setminus\{0\}$, and it is clear that $\nu(\psi)=0$ but $\nu(\varphi_{i})=1$, for every $i\geq 1$.

Answer (score 0):

*Below I'm assuming that "syntactically inequivalent" is a typo for "semantically inequivalent," since otherwise as GVT commented above the problem is trivial.*

---

In fact, there can never be such a $\psi$ - essentially, no nontrivial infinite conjunction is ever expressible by a first-order sentence.

To see this, suppose otherwise and consider the theory $$T=\{\neg\psi\}\cup\{\varphi_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\}.$$ If this is finitely satisfiable, then by compactness it is satisfiable and any model of $T$ witnesses $\{\varphi_i:i\in\mathbb{N}\}\not\models\psi$. So we just need to show that $T$ is finitely satisfiable.

Suppose $T_0\subset T$ is finite. WLOG, $T_0$ has the form $\{\neg\psi\}\cup\{\varphi_i: i\le n\}$ for some $n$. By assumption on the $\varphi_i$s, this is semantically equivalent to the sentence $\neg\psi\wedge\varphi_n$. Now if $\neg\psi\wedge\varphi_n$ were unsatisfiable, this would mean $\varphi_n\models\psi$. But since $\psi\models\varphi_i$ for every $i\in\mathbb{N}$ this would give e.g. $\varphi_n\models\varphi_{n+1}$, which - since $\varphi_{n+1}\models\varphi_n$ by assumption - would imply $\varphi_n\equiv\varphi_{n+1}$, contradicting the assumed inequivalence.

(Note that I'm writing e.g. "$\varphi_{n+1}\models\varphi_n$" instead of "$\models\varphi_{n+1}\rightarrow\varphi_n$." Of course, these are equivalent, and I find the former easier to think about.)